# How to trim values in an array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, trim

I got a problem I just cant fix. I have a string, want to split it at ";" (that is working) and then trim the values.

```
Dim cell As String
Dim objects() As String
cell = Range("X74").Text
objects= Trim(Split(cell, ";"))
```

I get my error on the Trim-function. I then tried the following approach:

```
For Each object In objects
        object = Trim(object)
        Debug.Print object
Next
```

This works, but doesnt save the trimmed value to my objects-array.

Comment: You have to Split then Trim.

Comment: Didnt I do that?

Comment: You tried to split the whole array in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite naming your variables `objects` and `object`, they are an array of simple Strings resp. a simple String, and in VBA a string is not an object.

In your `For Each`-Loop, you are *copying* a string to the variable `object`, and no matter what you do with it, it doesn't change the content of the `objects`-array.

If you really need to change the content of the `objects`-array, use a loop like that:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(objects) To UBound(objects)
    objects(i) = Trim(objects(i))
    Debug.Print objects(i)
Next
```

And you should think about changing the name of your variables...

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. That works! And I had my variables in German, only changed their names for overflow. But good to keep in mind!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid vba names as variables:

```
Sub tst()
    Dim yourcell As String, i As Long
    Dim yourobjects() As String
    yourcell = Range("X74").Text
    yourobjects = Split(yourcell, ";")
    For i = LBound(yourobjects) To UBound(yourobjects)
            yourobjects(i) = Trim(yourobjects(i))
            Debug.Print yourobjects(i)
    Next i
    End Sub
```